# JSP Class "cannot be resolved to a variable"

Tags: java, class, jsp, variables, resolve

Cordial Greetings:

cannot be resolved to a variable"
I have this error message in JSP File.

```
    <%@ page import="java.lang.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    <%@ page errorPage ="error.jsp"%>
    <%!
      public class User {
        private List<RTool> ListFam = new ArrayList<RTool>();
        private List<RTool> ListControl = new ArrayList<RTool>();
        private List<RTool> aList = new ArrayList<RTool>();
        private List<RTool> aLItem = new ArrayList<RTool>();

        User() {
        }
        public void AddRTool2(String Name) {
          RTool NewRTool = new RTool();
          String sFF = "sFF";
          NewRTool.Name = Name;
          NewRTool.Arg0 = sFF;
          this.ListFam.add(NewRTool);
        }
        public void AddRTool1(String Name) {
              String sCT = "SCT";
              NewRTool = new RTool();
              NewRTool.Name = Name;
              NewRTool.Arg0 = sCT;
              this.ListControl.add(NewRTool);
        }
      }
    %>
    <%!
      public class RTool {
        public String Name = "";
        public String Arg0 = "";
        public String Arg1 = "";
      }
    %>
```

As you can see, the error is post below....
How Can I to solve it?

This error Message:
type Informe de Excepción

mensaje

descripción El servidor encontró un error interno () que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: No se puede compilar la clase para JSP:

```
Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: 15 en el archivo jsp: /RTFProblemClass.jsp
NewRTool cannot be resolved to a variable
12:             User() {
13:             }
14:             public void AddRTool2(String Name) {
15:               RTool NewRTool = new RTool();
16:               String sFF = "sFF";
17:               NewRTool.Name = Name;
18:               NewRTool.Arg0 = sFF;
```

....

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:97)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)

Thank you for your valuable help.

Best Regards

Comment: What cannot be resolved to a variable?

Comment: Works Ok for me, maybe you problem is elsewhere

Comment: sorry, i put the code with the message

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of the class RTool comes after you tried to use it in the User class.  Do it the other way around.

And you don't need to import java.lang.*, everything in that package is always usable.

Answer (score -1):

you can build path, import jsp-api.jar and servlet-api.jar in your project lib,this two jars can be found in lib of tomcat.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question in any way.